# How to carry out a running total in SQL

Tags: sql, sum

I am carrying out a mini project and trying to run this script

```
select name,
[year ],
[Profit(millions)],
SUM [Profit(millions)], 
OVER(PARTITION BY [year ]  ORDER BY [year ]) RunningTotal
from Marvelmovies
Where [year ] >= 2010
```

However I am getting this error message

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'

What I am trying to do is to calculate the running profit total after a certain year, but alas that is not the case.

Would love to be pointed in the right direction on this.

Thanking you

Paul Mampilly.

Comment: You have a comma before `over`. I'm voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may work:-

```
select name,
[year ],
[Profit(millions)],
SUM [Profit(millions)]
OVER(PARTITION BY [year ]  ORDER BY [year ]) RunningTotal
from Marvelmovies
Where [year ] >= 2010
```